# SharePoint item not saving in List after Save

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a simple list created that is a little fuzzy:

When a new item is added to the list (through the "form") and the save button is clicked, it closes the form but does not add the item in the list. It also does not appear in the "Recent Activity" section - it basically appears that the item was not "created".

HOWEVER, when I do this using "test" items (just typing "test" in all fields and selecting random choices), it works.

I initially thought it was a copy paste/formatting issue with the data i was inputting, but even after pasting them as plain text, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you customized the form?

Try to let user who have full control permissions create items and compare the results.

Make sure you have not set filter on the view:
Modify view->in filter section, choose "Show all items in this view".

Make sure the item is not a draft.

Navigate to list settings->advanced settings->choose "read all items" and "create and edit all items":
[image]

Disable "Client Integration" in the Authentication settings for your web application.